# Python3 XML - Issue with <lsar>

Tags: xml, elementtree, python-3.3

I have an XML document with the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
    <lsar030 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.logsa.army.mil/alc/powerLOG-J/2006/report/lsar030" xmlns="http://www.logsa.army.mil/alc/powerLOG-J/2006/report/lsar030" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>...
```

I am using Python 33 and ElementTree to parse the XML. My problem is my code errors on:

```
    <lsar030 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.logsa.army.mil/alc/powerLOG-J/2006/report/lsar030" xmlns="http://www.logsa.army.mil/alc/powerLOG-J/2006/report/lsar030" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

If I manually replace this with:

```
    <doc>
```

(including the close block), the code works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Does lsar030 have a close block?

Comment: yes, at the end of the file. (where it should be)

Comment: Can you show us the entire file? Post it on a site like Pastebin.

Comment: No, I don't think I can share the rest of the file. I can say after <head> it is pretty straightforward. Also, I only change the <lsar...> & </lasr> block to <doc> & </doc> blocks respectively and that makes the difference between not working and working (respectively).

Comment: I can say that the error pops on this statement: 'title = tree.find('./head/item_name').text'  Error:xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: It seems ElementTree always says `line 1, column 0`. Is `tree` referring to <lsar> or the root element? And, are you sure it isn't a glitch? Have you tried lxml.etree or cElementTree?

Comment: The error actually refers to the 'title = tree.find('./head/item_name').text' (xpath) but it does so with the <lsar..> block in place. It may be a glitch with ElementTree - I have not tried anything else as I have just identified this issue today.

Comment: Try them and edit your post with the results. Also, if it isn't too much trouble, could you try xml.parsers.expat, xml.sax, or xml.dom? Just to make sure it isn't a glitch in the entire ElementTree concept, since, if it is, the others won't work either.

Comment: Ok, I tried cElementTree - same issue. I did experiment a little and printed all the tags found - an interesting development, all the tags were preceeded by '{http://www.logsa.army.mil/alc/powerLOG-J/2006/report/lsar030}' (refer to as JUNK for message brevity ;)). I.E. the <head> tag was actually: 'JUNKhead'. If I precede each tag in my xpath reference with the junk then it works. Example:  title = tree.find('./JUNKhead/JUNKitem_name').text.

Comment: Will the code work if you remove xsi:schemaLocation?

Comment: Yes, that removes the 'JUNK' problem.

Comment: Have you tried using xml.parsers.expat or xml.sax or xml.dom? Just to make sure it isn't a glitch in the entire ElementTree concept, which would result in lxml and cElementTree exhibiting the same behaviour.

Comment: No, I was going to, but I need to finish this first. I will revisit and approach with the xml.sax and xml.dom when I can push this out successfully. (I have folks waiting on this!) (I am not familiar with the those tools yet).

Comment: Give me about an hour and I'll post you the entire parser. All you'll need is the file.

Comment: In each of the parsers I wrote, just replace 'test.xml' with your XML's name. It's stored on line 3 of each one in the variable fname. Then run it, and it'll print every single tag. DOM: http://pastebin.com/AaivqKCE SAX: http://pastebin.com/RrQ9gE0p Expat: http://pastebin.com/SfF5n2ea. Try one and post the results.

Comment: DOM and SAX both worked as written (added () on print statements). XPAT parser returned an error: TypeError: read() did not return a bytes object (type=str)

Comment: Well, I'm on Python 2, so that explains a lot. I just changed the Expat one, so try it again. Did they show the same thing as ElementTree, or did they not have the junk?

Comment: They only printed the XML tag (without JUNK). Expat works now. Do you know where (on the web) I can learn to navigate using these parsers? I was dependent on the xpath feature of ElementTree. The XML is a list of a couple different groups of items with various attributes, and I have to 'translate' it into a different XML standard. The information is not one for one, so I have to be able to loop through and specify certain elements.

Comment: XPath for Minidom: http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/ Minidom tutorial: http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/parsing_xml.html SAX tutorial: http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/howto/section-SAX.html. An Expat example is available in the Python docs under module xml->parsers->expat. Good luck! Minidon has XPath support via the module link I provided, but it's slower than the other two. Expat doesn't have good docs, but it seems easy to work with and not too memory-hungry. SAX is a little confusing at first, but it's pretty good and the least memory hungry of the three.

Comment: Oh, and check out lxml still. It's just like ElementTree, but it's worth a try, since it uses a different parse(libxml2).

Comment: Can you post an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Sure! Oh, and I'd say try lxml first. It's API is just like ElementTree, so if it works, it'd be the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a glitch in ElementTree and cElementTree and (maybe, maybe not) lxml. Use MiniDOM, SAX, or Expat.